# Query turns an ascending average grouped by another atribute

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

I have 3 tables : `accident`, `involve` and `car`.

`Car (registration_nr, model,year) involve (licence_nr,registration_nr (FK of car), damages , raport_nr (FK of accident)) accident(raport_nr, date)`

I have to find the average of damages but must be `group by m.model`. I can find the averages but I cant group by model in ascending average.

```
SELECT 
AVG(damage),c.model
FROM
involve AS i
    JOIN
car AS c ON i.registration_nr = c.registration_nr
    JOIN
accident AS a ON i.raport_nr = a.raport_nr
GROUP BY m.model
```

Comment: add order by avg(damage) desc at the end

Comment: `select AVG(damage) avg_damage,c.model....order by avg_damage`

Comment: **GROUP BY m.model**? I do not see m alias... ;)

Comment: Is it just the order of your results that you're trying to change?

Comment: @MaciejLos I'm sorry I translated the query from my language to be easier to understand and I forgot that letter.